# How to dynamically change the Same Layout in Blazor Webassembly using an input parameter

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I have this use case for changing the Parent Layout Menu Item based on the razor page clicked.
For simplicity sake in the below sample Layout code i'm trying to see which child Razor page is trying to load the menu item and change the Menu item based on that.
I'm trying to avoid creating multiple layout files. If I understand it correctly Layouts only gets loaded once in the life cycle unless you refresh the browser
Please let me know if this is even possible.

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
    <ul id="zMenu">
    @if (RouteName.Contains("/packing_sky/"))
    {
    <li class='title'>Sky Packing</li>
    <li><a href='/Packing_sky'>Pack</a></li>
    }
    else if (RouteName.Contains("/cartpick/")) {
    <li class='title'>Sky Packing</li>
    <li><a href='/CartPick'>Pack</a></li>
    }
    </div>
@code{
    public String RouteName= "";
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        RouteName= "<from_razor_page>";
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are two ways to accomplish this behavior.

I will call the layout component `MainLayout`.

In the first approach, the `MainLayout` is responsible for "knowing" what link should be rendered. In essence, it is what you have done already. The `NavigationManager` has the needed properties for the current URL. So you need to inject it.

```
@inject NavigationManager navManager
```

You are also right that the `OnInitialized` method of `MainLayout` will only be called once. (To be more precious, it won't be called again if the page uses the same layout). However, the `NavigationManager` has an event you can subscribe to.

```
@code{
    public String RouteName = "";

    private void HandleLocationChanged(Object sender,LocationChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        RouteName = args.Location;
        //force an update of the UI, it might be necessary in some layouts and circumstances
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        RouteName = navManager.Uri;
        navManager.LocationChanged += HandleLocationChanged;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        navManager.LocationChanged -= HandleLocationChanged;
    }
}
```

The call to `StateHasChanged()` in the `HandleLocationChanged` method ensure that the layout is updated with the new value. This might not be necessary with every layout and every circumstance. I'd recommend to test it without it, and if it doesn't work, try it with `StateHasChanged()`.

I've implemented the `IDisposable` interface to unsubscribe from the event. This is only beneficial if your application has multiple layouts.

The second approach would be to use a service for communication between the `MainLayout` and your page component. It's like the page is "requesting" to display a link.

If you are interested in this solution, let me know, and I'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you , The approach #1 saved me a lot of code duplication.
I had to make one minor change in the HandleLocactionChanged method.
So I had to rebuild the HTML content again and set it via javascript as the page has got already loaded.

```
private void HandleLocationChanged(Object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs args)
{
    RouteName = args.Location;
    JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync(
                    "setHTML", new String[]{"zMenu", fetchMenuContent(RouteName)});
}
```

Comment: Could you try to call ```StateHasChanged()``` instead of the call to the javascript function? It should work without additional javascript.

Comment: That's awesome !! Just tried and it worked as expected. I don't need any patch-up JS code now. Thanks again !

Comment: That's great. I've updated my original answer. It would be nice if you could accept the answer so that others can find the solution more easily.